# Words with unconfigured accent using JSON column in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm having a problem with accenting (UTF-8) words in the data collected from the JSON column `properties`.

- Actually: "type_nen": "Emiss\u00e3o"
- Expected: "type_nen": "Emissão" (I want that be showed)

```
    public function store(HunterRequest $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();
        $validations['properties'] = $validations;
        HunterModel::create($validations);
        return redirect('/')->with('success_store','Hunter are registered in the system.');   
    }
```

Comment: Is this a problem (only) in your expectation or by handling the data? Per JSON, this should not cause any issues, this is why I'm asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: @hakren I specified how data with accents should be shown in my question. I finished of updated.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part, but its not clear to me where this arises as a programming question. To give a really stupid example (just for clarification): Store it differently so that this doesn't happen. This would be silly to give as an answer (most likely, sometimes we don't see the obvious), it is just not really clear what you try to achieve (you just made a problem statement but the code provided does not contain anyhing that is influencing _your preference_ of the JSON encoding, but the encoding is perfectly fine JSON. Now what would you suggest?